# Websphere MQ JMSTemplate setting ReplyTo

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to send message with `replyTo` property to WebSphere MQ.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WmqSenderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(WmqSenderApplication.class, args);
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = ctx.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        jmsTemplate.send("TEST_QUEUE",new MessageCreator() {

            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                message.setJMSReplyTo(new MQDestination("REPLY_QUEUE"));//com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination
                return message;
            }
        });

    }

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory connFac() throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        cf.setTransportType(1);
        cf.setHostName("localhost");
        cf.setPort(1417);
        cf.setQueueManager("TEST");
        cf.setChannel("CHANNEL");
        return cf;
    }
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        return new JmsTemplate(connFac());
    }
}
```

But I got:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: 
JMSCMQ0005: The destination name '://REPLY_QUEUE' was not valid. The destination name specified does not conform to published destination syntax. Correct the specified destination name and try again.
```

I got both `REPLY_QUEUE` and `TEST_QUEUE` created in the broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it with:

```
jmsTemplate.send("TEST_QUEUE",new MessageCreator() {

            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                Queue queue = session.createQueue("REPLY_QUEUE");
                message.setJMSReplyTo(queue);
                return message;
            }
        });
```

Comment: oh!.ok. Anyway see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The `setJMSReplyTo` method takes an object of type `javax.jms.Destination`. You will need to create an instance of a `javax.jms.Destination` class. You can create either a temporary queue or a permanent queue.

```
     Destination replyToQ = session.createQueue("REPLYQ");
     TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
     message.setJMSReplyTo(replyToQ);
     return message;
```